# pyspark - filter rows containing set of special characters

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, special-characters

I have a data frame as follow:-

```
df= 
    a    b     
   goat* bat    
   ki^ck ball
   range@ kick
   rick?  kill
```

Now I want to find the count of total special characters present in each column. So I have used `str. contains` function to find it, though it is running but it does not find the special characters.

```
code:-
special = df.filter(df['a'].contains('[\!\@\$\^\&\-\_\;\:\?\.\#\*]'))
print(special.count())

output:-  0
excepted output:- 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use [`rlike`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.rlike.html?highlight=rlike#pyspark.sql.Column.rlike) instead of `contains`, which allows to search for regular expressions

```
df.filter(df['a'].rlike('[\!\@\$\^\&\-\_\;\:\?\.\#\*]')).count()
# 4
```